# How do oceans in an O'Neill Cylinder replenish dissolved oxygen?

Tags: internal-consistency, space-constructs, habitability, ocean

I am concerned that the centrifugal force will draw out all the dissolved gases from the ocean in a colossal O'Neill Cylinder in the same way blood centrifuges do in lab.  Fishes and most marine life would die from hypoxemia and laying gas pipes stretching thousands of miles may not be a cost effective solution.

First thing first, is this a baseless concern, and the effect would not be sufficient to harm the ecosystem, or would the threat come in another form which would be much more severe?

Comment: It seems to me that in a typical size O'Neil cylinder bodies of water would be ponds and lakes, not ocean sized.  Exactly how large do you want those O'Neil cylinders to be and how structurally strong would they be?  Your reference to "oceans" makes it seem possible that that you desire cylinders too large to hold together with present day materials.

Comment: O'Neil cylinder is only 8 km in diameter - not enough to support an ocean. Maybe you mean "O'Neil cylinder" in more general sense (like [McKendree cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McKendree_cylinder)) to suit your scale?

Comment: Assuming that the outer level is 1g, and that the bottom of the "ocean" is 1.5g, then no. Centrifuges produce a much higher gravitational gradient.

Comment: most of your oxygen is going to come from marine algae just like earth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Centrifuges that separate blood spin at a high RPM simulating between 500 and 2000 times Earth gravity.  So with your O'Neill Cylinders spinning at ~1G you will still have this problem (when it comes to important minerals settling), but WAY slower.

On Earth, collating of the Ocean is prevented by tidal forces caused by the sun and moon.  These forces help keep water churning in a way that it both absorbs and distributes atmospheric oxygen and kicks up minerals for plankton to consume.

The issue with O'Neill Cylinders comes into play when they are tidally locked to thier star and not in orbit of a planet.  In this case, there is no significant forces causing still bodies of water to churn and you would still get the hypoxia die off and mineral deprivation you are worrying about, just much slower than you would in a centrifuge, and for slightly different reasons.  That said, this can easily be solved for through a variety of means including something as simple as using a [staggered re-spin cycle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/181124/57832)

Comment: Or have fans and pumps working underewater for artificial currents and waves (+1).

Comment: @Renan Yes, that was my first thought too but artificial currents at that scale are enormously expensive.  If you need fish that badly, and you don't have any planets you could use, then from an engineering perspective if makes much more sense to just farm them in smaller more manageable aquarium tanks than naturalistic oceans.

Comment: I think if you have the resources to build an O'Neill cylinder, artificial currents would be cheap by comparison.

Comment: Not necessarily, the cost of an O'Neill cylinder would be expected to be distributed over the cost of its lifetime which is hopefully thousands if not millions of years.  One time costs like getting things spinning can be big while the maintenance of said systems small if you do it right, but keeping the water from syncing up with the movements of the ring would would require a constant exertion of energy rather than a 1 time cost.  Not saying it isn't an option with the right tech available, just that it is by comparison a costly one.

Comment: I'd think the cylinder's orbit around the sun would induce tides on the cylinder's oceans.

Comment: This started with an answer and turned into a brand new question. Perhaps you should post it.

Comment: @SurpriseDog yes... I see that I totally opened that can of worms, so:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/181119/how-to-simulate-tidal-currents-on-an-oneill-cylinder

Comment: Full disclosure, my followup question does have a lot of stipulations that this OP did not give because I see this becoming really opinion based when you allow clarke tech, not because I'm trying to railroad a specific solution.

Comment: Fish tanks use a bubbler.

Comment: @Nosajimiki That's not how cost amortization works. It's just an accounting trick. In reality, you still need to pay the entire cost up-front. The tax office may let you spread the cost of building the cylinder over 10000 years, but unless you *actually* take 10000 years to build it, you still need to buy all the materials first.

Comment: @user253751 If you have a REALLY big and expensive power source, that you only need for 1 year to get the project moving, then you can move that powersource on to building another station next year while leaving the first one running on a smaller cheaper power source.  This means in 10,000 years your 1 big powersource could give you 10,000 habitats, or it could be left at the first one just to keep it going.  Then your 10,000 habitats will be able to make another big powersource 10,000 times as easily as the single habitat.

Comment: Perhaps a better analogy is weather proofing a house. Through better design you can make the total cost of home ownership less by reducing the cost to maintain it.

Comment: " So with your O'Neill Cylinders spinning at ~1G you will still have this problem, but WAY slower." No. You need to get your physics right. If you manage to have no flow at all in your cylinder, thermodynamics dictate that you reach a (minuscule) static gradient.

Comment: @Karl I was a bit unclear.  You will get nutrient deprivation for the same reason as with a a centrifuge because water and many vital minerals form a colloid that will settle overtime.  Oxygen deprivation will happen because lack of churning means the water will not be absorbing enough atmospheric oxygen.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Indeed, but that assumes you are building 10000 habitats.  If you are building only 1 habitat, the fact that you could build 10000 in parallel does not help you.

Comment: @user253751 I think my examples are getting lost in translation; so, let's look at this as pure economics.  Even a species that has the ability to create megastructures still have to deal with the basic principles of scarcity. In a highly automated society, your annual power budget is going to be directly proportional to your GDP; so, such a civilization that only uses 70% of its power budget on sustenance will have much more "disposable income" than one that uses up 95% allowing them to invest more in other things. (if that is more habitats or power sources or what not is up to them)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are being paranoid. Are you worried about gravity doing the same thing on Earth? The O'Neil cylinder shouldn't be spinning fast enough to produce a force any greater since it is just trying to simulate 1G after all.

Comment: Having a moon rather helps earth's oceans in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is similar to a large fish tank.  The fish tank is basically still water and will eventually be deprived of oxygen throughout the tank.  This is due to the surface conditions more than the pull of gravity.  In small tanks, this is alleviated with small bubbles that forced from an air pump.  In larger tanks, you will usually see some type of waterfall that drops into the water and drags new oxygen into the tank water with the plummeting water using a water pump.  The speed this happens depends on surface area to depth ratio, wind, sea life, and atmospheric oxygen levels (and likely many others).

You could have waterfalls in parks for people where the now highly oxygenated water would flow into the sea or recycle the air by bubbling it through the water.